# Can git split a commit that was upstream using a revert?

Tags: git

I have a repo that is pushed to a remote **and** downloaded by others. Within the history is a bug introduced by a commit I made. Embarrassingly that commit it unwieldy (too much logic in one commit). Aside from going back in time and whacking my past self with a wet noodle the proper thing to do would be an interactive rebase to split the commit into several.

Sadly this has already been pushed and cloned by others (who would be very unpleased if I rebased from underneath them). So I thought I could branch, revert commit, cherry-pick commit, interactive rebase, then merge. Is this the best option or am I missing something?

Can I split a published commit by reverting then splitting?

```
A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
      ^- WTF commit


A--B--C--D--E--F-------------------M (master origin/master)
                \                 /
                 G--C1--C2--C3--C4   (split-and-fix-branch)
                 ^- revert commit C
```

Comment: That looks exactly right, it'd certainly be my first attempt and I'd expect it to work.  If your team doesn't mind you could even fast-forward F to C4 and skip the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my instinct is correct. The following lays out how to split/edit a commit that has already been pushed and pulled.

**EDIT:** Modified procedure with suggestions from comments.

**If this is local only use `get rebase -i` instead.**

```
A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
      ^- WTF Commit

$ git checkout -b split-n-fix C

A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
      ^ (split-n-fix)

$ git revert C

A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
       \
        R (split-n-fix)

$ git cherry-pick --no-commit C

A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
       \
        R--(dirty) (split-n-fix)

$ git add -p
$ git commit
(repeat till finished)

A--B--C--D--E--F (master origin/master)
       \
        R--C1--C2--C3--C4 (split-n-fix)

$ git checkout master
$ git merge split-n-fix
$ git branch -d split-n-fix

A--B--C--D--E--F----------M (master origin/master)
       \                 /
        R--C1--C2--C3--C4

$ git push
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: use `cherry-pick --no-commit` (or `-n`) to avoid the `reset` step.  (Also you don't actually need a separate branch if you're going to fast-forward, but it may help you keep track of what you are doing.)

Comment: To me, it would make more sense to do this work directly on top of the bad commit, so as to more closely tie it together with the original source of the problem.  So the first step would become `git checkout -b split-n-fix C`.  Then the merge is no longer a fast-forward, but I'm not sure that's really an issue.

Comment: @MattMcHenry Boy do I like that idea.  If you add it as a nice concise answer with a pretty picture and everything I'll vote.

Comment: @jthill, matt-mchenry, and torek I updated the answer to reflect your suggestions.